# Why am I getting multiple files when I save a Wand Image?

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, wand

I have the following code:

```
def resizeImg(img, width, height):
    outerImg = img(width=width, height=height, background=Color("WHITE"))
    outerImg.units='pixelsperinch'
    outerImg.resolution = (300, 300)
    outerImg.format = img.format.lower()
    outerImg.composite_channel('undefined', img, 'over', int((width - img.width) / 2), int((height - img.height) / 2))
    return outerImg

for file in os.listdir(): 
    if os.path.splitext(file)[1] in ('.tif', '.jpeg', '.jpg'): 
            
        with Image() as img: 
            
            fname = ntpath.basename(file).split('.')[0] # BC154360-ANG
            img.read(filename=file)
            img.units='pixelsperinch'
            img.resolution = (300, 300) 
            img.compression_quality = 99 
            img.format = 'jpg' 
            dim = max(img.width, img.height) 
            img.resize(height=dim, width=dim) # make image square
            img.resize(height=1500, width=1500) # set image size to 1500x1500
            img.units='pixelsperinch'
            img.resolution = (72, 72)
            img.save(filename = jpg_location + fname + '.jpg') # .jpg
```

The issue is that I am getting multiple files when I run this, and they're all slightly different. It seems as if each image has been processed differently. The "-0" image appears to be correct, as does the result when I run `display(img)`.

[image: The results of running the above code block. The first image is correct.]

Can someone explain what is going on here? Perhaps it is the result of the `channel` and `operator` parameters in the `composite_channel` function?

Comment: This is expected behavior. The input `.tif` images support layers, but the output `.jpg` image does not. ImageMagick will write each layer as a new image unless you merge and/or merge them.

Comment: @emcconville that makes sense, but where are these layers coming from? The original `.tif` files I am processing do not have multiple pages. Since the first image appears correct, ("...-ANG-0") what would merging these layers result in?